# HTML div height is different when shown with and without an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a chunk of html that is dynamically generated. We show it both directly in a page and embed it into an iframe. The strange thing is the div block shown in two places has different height even through all styles are the same. The code is below and the live result is shown in the codepen(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdKVqX). Anybody have ideas why this is happening? much appreciated.

Html content

```
<div class="height-diff" style="width: 198px; font-size: 30px;">
  <span style="font-size:12px">
    <span>Barlett Knit</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The same content as above, but inject into an iframe

```
var html = '<style>.height-diff {background-color: green;}</style> 
            <div class="height-diff" style="width: 198px; font-size: 30px;">
               <span style="font-size:12px">
                  <span>Barlett Knit</span>
               </span>
            </div>';

var doc = window.document;
iframe = doc.createElement("iframe"),
style = iframe.style;

iframe.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
iframe.setAttribute("allowFullscreen", "true");
doc.body.appendChild(iframe);

var contentDocument = iframe.contentDocument;

contentDocument.open();
contentDocument.write(html);
contentDocument.close();
```

Comment: That is a completely different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:** Your iframe html does not have a `<doctype>` declared and it is going into [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). See [codepen with doctype](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPKLza) added. I can't believe I didn't notice that earlier.

<strike>This appears to be happening because you have not specified a line-height.
See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPKWaa) with line-height added. This also seems to be a rendering bug. It appears white space is being added before the span in the primary document but not in the iframe. It is strange but Height is calculated correctly if you add other characters around the span or set the span to `display:block;`.</strike> Edit: Not strange, just quirks mode.

```
<div class="height-diff" style="width: 198px; font-size: 30px;line-height:1.2em;">
  &nbsp;    
  <span style="font-size:12px">
    <span>Barlett Knit</span>
  </span>
  &nbsp; 
</div>
<br />
<div class="height-diff" style="width: 198px; font-size: 30px;line-height:1.2em;">
  <span style="font-size:12px; display:block;">
    <span style="display:block;">Barlett Knit</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But if you inspect the elements, they actually don't have the same height.

Comment: Updated answer. Your iframe content needs a `doctype` declared.

Comment: That is awesome, can't believe how much time we have spent on this. if only I could vote many times. :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exact answer, but i found when both element height will be the same. Add some characters (non white characters) directly to div element which you write to iframe.

I don't know why, but in opposite to the div element written by JS, div element in the HTML see characters inside it. Therefore adjust height of element to font-size;. It happen even if  there is no direct characters inside.